# Is it possible to have a complex gauge field?

Tags: gauge-theory, complex-numbers, yang-mills

Beyond the obvious fact that the particles in the standard model described by gauge fields do not have an anti-particle pair, is there a reason why a complex gauge field is typically not considered?

Superficially it would seem preferable to consider such a theory, since it would allow more symmetry in the theory, like a $U(1)$ symmetry $$A_{\mu}\to e^{i\alpha}A_{\mu}$$

Or one could imagine a non-abelian symmetry that the gauge field transforms in the same way as ordinary matter under this other symmetry. One could then gauge that symmetry and have another gauge field which preserves that symmetry. In this way you could construct a tower of gauge fields which preserve all of these symmetries.

**Edit:**

What I am thinking of is say we have an action for an abelian gauge field (we can make the appropriate generalization for the non-abelian case) of the form
$$S=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^4x(F_{\mu\nu})^*F^{\mu\nu}$$

Instead of $A_{\mu}:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ being a set of real functions, we have $A_{\mu}:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{C}^4$.

In this situation there are two $U(1)$ symmetries. One which acts locally, with $A_{\mu}\to A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\Lambda$, and one which acts globally, with $A_{\mu}\to e^{i\alpha}A_{\mu}$.

Comment: $W^\pm{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: Are those complex? If so, woops!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "complex gauge field". A gauge field is valued in the Lie algebra of some group. Your transformation there doesn't work not because it's complex, but because it involves a *group* element $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha}\in\mathrm{U}(1)$ instead of two algebra elements - a solitary group element cannot act on an algebra element (only by conjugation if it appears twice). Whether the Lie algebra the gauge field is valued in is real or complexified is rather irrelevant.

Comment: The local symmetry the gauge field helps to preserve is different from the $U(1)$ I am referring to. I will make an edit to the question.